# Convergence of sum of function values when the function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f : \mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$ be continuous and have $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) dx < \infty$. Also let $I=[0,1]$. For some $c \geq 1$ define $F_n : I \to [0,\infty)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ by 
$$
F_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n f(x + ck).
$$
I'll let $F(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(x)$. Basically I'm looking at picking a point $x\in I$ and summing all the values of $f$ on the translations $\{x + ck : k\in \mathbb N\}$.

My question: does $(F_n)$ converge uniformly over $I$?

I suspect so because $\int f < \infty$ means $f$ gets small quickly, so no matter my $x\in I$ I should be able to choose $N$ large enough to have $\sup_{x\in I}|F_n(x) - F(x)| < \varepsilon$ for $n\geq N$, but I haven't been able to prove this. I wonder if it's not true unless I add more regularity conditions on $f$, like maybe monotonicity?

Comment: [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958346/f-in-l-10-infty-lambda-then-sum-n-0-inftyfnt-infty/1959128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $f$ need not get small quickly. On each interval $[n,n+1], n=1,2,\dots$ consider the isosceles triangle over the midpoint, of height $n$ and base $1/n^3.$ Define $f$ to be upper part of that triangle on each of those intervals. Everywhere else define $f=0.$ Then $f$ is continuous and nonnegative, and

$$\int_0^\infty f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2n^3}<\infty.$$

This should help in thinking about uniform continuity.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it was very helpful. What if I only need for $(F_n)$ to converge on almost all $x\in I$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes you get that from the MCT.

Comment: ah yeah i've been so focused on DCT I forgot about MCT. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome certainly.